# Can i use Wordpress admin panel to make changes to the website i developed?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, phpmyadmin, frontend

I've developed a website using(Html,css,JS,PHP)  its in localhost and i was wondering if i can use Wordpress admin panel to do changes on my website as an admin instead of building an admin panel myself.
Can anyone help me please how to get this done.

Comment: best option is change  your  html,css,js theme to wordpress theme.
finally wordpress have be your panel.

Comment: If your website uses Wordpress as CMS (content management system), the admin panel will be the Wordpress one. If your website is just a collection of custom built scripts, or uses a CMS that you built, than no. Imagine asking "can I open my house doors with a piece of rock floating in Pluto's orbit"?